# Fixing Javadoc Errors for Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, javadoc

I'm trying to edit javadocs of an existing application to be Java-8 compitable. I don't wanna skip checking that errors. I wanna fix them. I've confused at HTML tags i.e.:

```
<code></code>
<ul></ul>
<li></li>
<ol></ol>
```

I know that I can use `@code` for `<code></code>` etc. but there are many HTML tags and they are not allowed according to javadoc. I've tried to escape them, i.e.:

```
&lt;code&gt;&lt;/code&gt;
&lt;ul&gt;&lt;/ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;/li&gt;
&lt;ol&gt;&lt;/ol&gt;
```

However they are printed as text at Javadoc as usual, not as HTML tags. I can see that it writes `<code></code>` at corresponding places of Javadoc.

How can I fix such errors of Javadoc at Java 8?

Comment: So, what is the code causing the error, and what is the error?

Comment: Why do you believe you can't use HTML tags in the javadoc for Java 8? The [javadoc manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javadoc.html) for Java 8 says you can: *text must be written in HTML with HTML entities and HTML tags [...] HTML 4.0 is preferred [...] entities for the less than symbol (<) and the greater than symbol (>) should be written as &lt; and &gt;. Similarly, the ampersand (&) should be written as &amp;*

Comment: And where did you find that HTML tags are not allowed? People argue if it is a good **idea** to do that; but technically, that works fine. Our team agrees on HTML tag; so our javadoc has many of them; and all of that works nicely. The only reason to **not** use them would be "convention".

Comment: Well, if you escape HTML tags, they are printed as text. That shouldn’t surprise you. What did you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadoc checks for valid HTMLs at Java 8. So, you should not need to escape anything, just obey the rules for a valid HTML style.